# UIWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest — getting the anchor's text

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView and a shouldStartLoadWithRequest method. In the web view, there might be a link something like this: `<a href="http://whatever/whateverelse">This is the title</a>` and when the link is clicked, I need to fetch the `This is the title` out. Is there a way to get this from the NSURLRequest that's passed?